# test if a byte array is empty in C#

Tags: c#

I have a function to get data from a network endpoint

```
public Byte[] GetData(string ip, int port ,Byte [] query, int responseLen)
{            
    Connection connection = GetConnection(ip,port);
    Byte[] data;
    try
    {
        data = connection.GetData(query, responseLen);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //return an empty array
        data = new Byte[] { };
    }
    return data;
}
```

In case there is an exception from `GetData` function I am returning an empty array to the caller of `GetData` function.

I want to know how the caller can test if the byte array returned is empty or non-empty

Comment: check if is not null and if length > 0

Comment: null and empty are not the same thing. Be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about the (new) [null propagation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)!  The shortest check is

```
if (data?.Length > 0)
{
    //Data were returned
}
else
{
    //An error occurred
}
```

If you're on an older version of c# you can use Prabhath's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data != null  && data.Length > 0)
```

try this